# What movie about a virtual reality game is this?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Around 2005-2010 I watched a movie:

- I *believe* there was a female and male lead
- The movie did not seem like one of the really high budget movies
- They are part of a game and they are in a virtual reality somewhere. I distinctly remember that they have metal detectors and therefore smuggled guns made out of organic material.
- I seem to recall there being a lot of secrecy and hiding
- There is some sort of plot twist / open interpretation in the end scene when they return from the game and it is unclear whether they are still in a game or if they have returned to reality. A lot of people are sitting in a circle connected to they "VR headsets" or something similar.

What is the name of this movie?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"eXistenZ" (1999) by David Cronenberg

Per wikipedia, it had a budget of $15 million dollars (US).

Per the [wikipedia article's plot description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existenz):

> Antenna Research's Allegra Geller (Jennifer Jason Leigh), the world's preeminent game designer, is testing her latest virtual reality game, eXistenZ, with a focus group at a seminar. She is shot in the shoulder by an assassin named Noel Dichter (Kris Lemche) with an **organic pistol**, which is undetectable by security. As Dichter is gunned down by the security team, security guard (and marketing trainee) Ted Pikul (Jude Law) rushes to Geller and escorts her outside.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I remember this movie! I remember the organic gun that shot teeth, which I'm pretty sure were the would-be assassin's....

Comment: @Luciano thanks for the edit suggestion, but the youtube link works fine on this end of the internet.

Comment: What a remarkable cast for such a ... dubious-looking film.